# Solve it manually

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let the matrices $A$ and $B$ be defined as $A=$
$\begin{bmatrix}
   3 & 2\\
   2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=$
$\begin{bmatrix}
   3 & 1\\
   7 & 3\\
\end{bmatrix}$ then the value of $|2A^{9}B^{-1}|$ is:
$(A)$ $2$  $(B)$ $1$  $(C)$ $-1$  $(D)$ $-2$.

In the above question do we have to solve each and every term manually as power of A is $9$ or is there some other method , shortcut or a trick? Thank you.

Comment: Pictures of text are not acceptable on this site. Please type out your question.

Comment: Hint: det$(AB)=$ det$(A)$ det $(B)$.

Comment: [This guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tells you how to format mathematics nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Provided we are dealing with square matrices, then $\det(A B) = \det(A) \det(B)$. Thus,
$$\det(2 I A^9 B^{-1}) = \det(2 I) \det(A)^9 \det(B)^{-1}.$$
So no, you don't need to compute $A^9$ or even $B^{-1}$ for that matter.

Further hint: Be careful finding $\det(2I)$. It is probably not what you think it is.